# How to listen for click inside an iframe in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, listener, onclicklistener

I'm using an iframe to display a fetched HTML document in React and would like to listen for clicks on DOM elements inside the iframe.

For example I would like to console.log the DOM element I've clicked inside the iframe

I've tried using useRef and onClick but it doesn't seem to be working on the iFrame

I'm using Next.js to fetch the website HTML before adding to the the iframe

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState()
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const getDownload = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/getWebsite')
    const data = await response.json()
    setHtml(data)
  }


  return (
    <main>
    <iframe srcDoc={html} ref={ref} ></iframe>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Share you code with us

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: You can't, no modern browser will let you listen for clicks _inside_ an iframe because of super obvious security concerns. If I load paypal or facebook or really anything in an iframe, never in a million years should I be able to listen to events on those pages. Your own content doesn't need iframes, and you have no rights to external content. Your only means of communication between your page and iframes on that page is the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `contentDocument` of the frame after it loads.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const frame = ref.current;
    function loadHandler() {
      frame.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log('clicked', e.target);
      });
    }
    frame.addEventListener('load', loadHandler);
    return () => frame.removeEventListener('load', loadHandler);
}, []);
```

Comment: [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-tristan-tdyqcy?file=/src/App.js) (open the console to see the output)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for providing the example!